# I want to return two json data in show action in Rails API mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## What I want to come true

Show I want to return two JSON data after receiving a request. What should I do now.
One is the received parameter data. The second is the related data.
post_items is the associated data.

## Code

```rb
    def show
        post = Post.find(params[:id])
        content = post.post_items 　# I want to return this
        render json: post // content...
    end
```

## What I tried myself and error

① Two`render :json`

```rb
    def show
        post = Post.find(params[:id])
        content = post.post_items
        render json: post, status: 200 
        render json: content, status: 200 //add
    end
```

error

```
 AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".)
```

Now I know that I can't render twice

② I used respond_to

```rb
    def show
        post = Post.find(params[:id])
        content = post.post_items
        respond_to do |format|
        format.json  { render json: post  }
        format.json  { render json: content }
    end
```

error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `respond_to' for #<Api::V1::PostsController:0x00005612037f95c0>
api_1    | Did you mean?  respond_to?
api_1    |                respond_with
api_1    |                responder
api_1    |                responder?
api_1    |                responder=):
api_1    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to return one json object with your two sub-objects posts, content under different keys.

```rb
render json: {"post": post, "content": content}, status: 200
```

Returns the json

```json
{"post": ... , "content": ... }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I see, I should have used the key.

Answer (score 1):

In this case,

Add this line to your application's Gemfile:

```
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.2'
```

And then execute:

```
$ bundle
```

And then generate model serializers

```
rails g serializer post
```

All serializer `.rb` files grouped in `app/serializers`

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :description
end
```

if you want content data with post then, add association to serializer

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :post_items
  attributes :id, :title, :description, :post_items
end
```

In controller,

```
def show
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    render json: post
end
```

It will return the `post` data and related `post_items` data

```
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "",
      description: "",
      post_items: {
       {
        id: 1,
        name: ""
       }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is it common to use this normally?